# How do i serialize a excel file stream?

Tags: json, excel, stream, memorystream, closedxml

I need to convert the Excel file into a stream with XLWorkbook (using ClosedXML.Excel) and then serialize with JSON format (Newtonsoft.Json) but a code error appears.

I already have a excel file saved in a disk at c:\Temp.
The error is:

> ***Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.IO.MemoryStream'.***

It happens when I try to serialize the object reportResult as you can see below

```
string jsonReportResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reportResult)
```

How could I serialize a stream ?

I created a excel file using XLWorkbook then saved into a stream.
After I have done a stream I tried to serialize the stream into json but this code error appears

```
workBookSGBBDIT.SaveAs(@$"{filePath}");
Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
workBookSGBBDIT.SaveAs(stream);
this._linkDownload = new MemoryStream();
this._linkDownload = stream;

Result result = CreateResult("Teste concluído", "OK", this._linkDownload);
string jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

Error occurs at this last line.